# read QDate from Qtablewidget and store it on QDate

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qdate

I have a problem with qdate and qtablewidget.

When I update an item on a qtablewdiget through a connect, I call a function "updateProdotto".
I have a problem in reading the new qdate that I insert and in storing it in a new qdate variable.

I have already searched in the web, but without results because nobody does the operation I neeed with the qdate type.

```
connect(ui->tableViewProdotti,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(updateProdotto())); 

void UserInterface::updateProdotto() {
int colonna = ui->tableViewProdotti->currentColumn();
int riga = ui->tableViewProdotti->currentRow();

if(colonna == 1)
    art[riga]->setNome(ui->tableViewProdotti->item(riga,1)->text().toStdString());
if(colonna == 2)
    art[riga]->setCategoria(ui->tableViewProdotti->item(riga,2)->text().toStdString());
 if(colonna == 5) { // this is for date
   QDate date= // read date and store it
   art[riga]->setDate(date);
 }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use `QDate::fromString` and don't forget to specify correct format:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you would have a date in *string* and now you would need to use it as a `QDate` object. In this case, you should parse the string using `QDate:fromString` static method.

Method signature:

```
QDate QDate::fromString(const QString & string, const QString & format)
```

Example:

```
QDate date = QDate::fromString("1MM12car2003", "d'MM'MMcaryyyy");
// date is 1 December 2003
```

Documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1

Answer (score 0):

thank you, I already know about "QDate::fromstring" but in my case it doesn't work. I use QDate::fromString in other function of my project but in this case the right solution ( 2 houres for it after read your answers) its:

```
    QString format="yyyy-MM-dd";
    QTableWidgetItem* date= ui->tableViewProdotti->item(riga,5);
    QString text=date->text();
    QDate date1=QDate::fromString(text,format);
    art[riga]->setDataAcquisto(date1);
```

My error was on QTableWidgetItem pointer and the format is yyyy-MM-dd ( like standard) and in the other function I used dd.MM.yyyy ( I'm european!)

thank you for your help, I hope this solution can help other people!